# How do I load a dynamic contact form which has a link in every page in my wordpress website

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a WordPress website, with a contact form link in all my pages. When clicking the "contact us" link, there should open a div (dynamically) in the center of the page and send the information (dynamically too)...

Correct me if I'm wrong, but including the same HTML code of the undisplayed div with all the Javascript functions will make the load time of my page/s too long.

Is there a way to pull out the HTML only if clicked on the contact from? Maybe getting it from an external HTML file ?

What's the efficient way to do this using WP ?

Comment: I would just load the HTML needed to display the form on each page.  It shouldn't make that big of a difference on loading time.  You're going to need to have the JS available to show the popup anyway.

Comment: I don't think you should worry about the html of your pages being a bit longer. Unless you have an _extremely_ bandwidth/performance sensitive site, the different will be negligible.